# PyCUDA context error when using Flask

Tags: python, image-processing, flask, server, pycuda

I am using the PyCUDA to implement the smooth_local_affine as shown [here](https://github.com/LouieYang/deep-photo-styletransfer-tf/blob/master/smooth_local_affine.py). It works well when I simply run the program on linux. But when I tried to import it under Flask context:

```
from smooth_local_affine import smooth_local_affine
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(_name_)
...
```

The following error occurs:

> ```
> -------------------------------------------------------------------  
> PyCUDA ERROR: The context stack was not empty upon module cleanup.
> -------------------------------------------------------------------   
> A context was still active when the context stack was being cleaned up.  
> At this point in our execution, CUDA may already have been deinitialized, 
> so there is no way we can finish cleanly. The program will be aborted now. 
> Use Context.pop() to avoid this problem.
> ```

Then I tried to add `context.pop()`,then another error occurs;

> Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/home/yifang/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycuda-2017.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/autoinit.py",
>   line 14, in _finish_up
>       context.pop() pycuda._driver.LogicError: context::pop failed: invalid device context - cannot pop non-current context

Anyone knows how to run PyCuda in Flask environment? Or maybe any alternative ways that I can use this smooth_local_affine feature without using PyCuda?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50920361/7116413)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyCUDA with Flask gives pycuda.\_driver.LogicError: cuModuleLoadDataEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601029/pycuda-with-flask-gives-pycuda-driver-logicerror-cumoduleloaddataex)

Answer (score 4):

Let me present one solution here because I have tried a lot of solutions but still not work. Fortunately I found one correct answer.

some solutions like

```
import pycuda.autoinit
```

or

```
cuda.init 
device = cuda.Device(0) 
ctx = device.make_context() 
inputs, outputs, bindings, stream = allocate_buffer() 
ctx.pop()
```

these may work if you run the script as simple program, but it will raise context error if you run with flask or other web servers. According to my searching, the reason is possibally that flask server would spawn new thread when a request came in.

The real solution in such a circumstance is quite simple and you should just add code like this:

```
with engine.create_execution_context() as context:
    ctx = cuda.Context.attach()
    inputs, outputs, bindings, stream = allocate_buffer()
    ctx.detach()
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

Starting the Flask application in non-threaded mode worked for me

```
app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT, debug=False,threaded=False)
```

Comment: It is cool solution, worked for me. I use TensorRT engine with Flask ! In Flask init context  `with app.app_context():` , i create context, runtime and engine for TensorRT. In POST method, i processing image in last context, engine and runtime all in one thread !