# get "LogicError: explicit_context_dependent failed: invalid device context - no currently active context? " when running tensorRT in ROS

Tags: python-2.7, ros, pycuda, tensorrt

I have an inference code in TensorRT(with python). I want to run this code in ROS but I get the below error when trying to allocate buffer:

`LogicError: explicit_context_dependent failed: invalid device context - no currently active context?`

The code works well out of the ROS package. A ROS node publishes an image and the given code get the image to do inference. The inference code is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Revision $Id$

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import argparse
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import transforms
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch._utils
from PIL import Image
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image as ImageMsg
import tensorrt as trt
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import random
import sys
import common
import shutil
from itertools import chain


TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger()
# cuda.init()


class ModelData(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.MODEL_PATH = "./MobileNet_v2_Final.onnx" ## converted model from pytorch to onnx

        self.batch_size = 1
        self.num_classes = 3


        self.engine = build_int8_engine(self.MODEL_PATH, self.batch_size)
        self.context = self.engine.create_execution_context()


        ### ROS PART
        self.bridge_ROS = CvBridge()
        self.loop_rate = rospy.Rate(1)
        self.pub = rospy.Publisher('Image_Label', String, queue_size=1)

        print('INIT Successfully')

    def callback(self, msg):
        rospy.loginfo('Image received...')

        cv_image = self.bridge_ROS.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, desired_encoding="passthrough")

        inputs, outputs, bindings, stream = common.allocate_buffers(context.engine)
        [output] = common.do_inference(context, bindings=bindings, inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, stream=stream, batch_size=effective_batch_size)



    def listener(self):

        rospy.Subscriber("chatter", ImageMsg, self.callback)

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            rospy.loginfo('Getting image...')
            self.loop_rate.sleep()


def build_int8_engine(model_file, batch_size=32):
    with trt.Builder(TRT_LOGGER) as builder, builder.create_network() as network, trt.OnnxParser(network, TRT_LOGGER) as parser:
        builder.max_batch_size = batch_size
        builder.max_workspace_size = common.GiB(1)

        with open(model_file, 'rb') as model:
            parser.parse(model.read(),)

        return builder.build_cuda_engine(network)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("listener", anonymous=True)
    infer = ModelData()
    infer.listener()
```

The error comes from the below class in stream = cuda.Stream():

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Revision $Id$

from itertools import chain
import argparse
import os
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np
import tensorrt as trt

# Simple helper data class that's a little nicer to use than a 2-tuple.
class HostDeviceMem(object):
    def __init__(self, host_mem, device_mem):
        self.host = host_mem
        self.device = device_mem


    def __str__(self):
        return "Host:\n" + str(self.host) + "\nDevice:\n" + str(self.device)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

# Allocates all buffers required for an engine, i.e. host/device inputs/outputs.
def allocate_buffers(engine):
    inputs = []
    outputs = []
    bindings = []
    stream = cuda.Stream()
    for binding in engine:
        size = trt.volume(engine.get_binding_shape(binding)) * engine.max_batch_size
        dtype = trt.nptype(engine.get_binding_dtype(binding))
        # Allocate host and device buffers
        host_mem = cuda.pagelocked_empty(size, dtype)
        device_mem = cuda.mem_alloc(host_mem.nbytes)
        # Append the device buffer to device bindings.
        bindings.append(int(device_mem))
        # Append to the appropriate list.
        if engine.binding_is_input(binding):
            inputs.append(HostDeviceMem(host_mem, device_mem))
        else:
            outputs.append(HostDeviceMem(host_mem, device_mem))
    ctx.pop()
    del ctx
    return inputs, outputs, bindings, stream

# This function is generalized for multiple inputs/outputs.
# inputs and outputs are expected to be lists of HostDeviceMem objects.
def do_inference(context, bindings, inputs, outputs, batch_size=1):
    # Transfer input data to the GPU.
    [cuda.memcpy_htod_async(inp.device, inp.host, stream) for inp in inputs]
    # [cuda.memcpy_htod(inp.device, inp.host) for inp in inputs]
    # Run inference.
    context.execute_async(batch_size=batch_size, bindings=bindings, stream_handle=stream.handle)
    # context.execute(batch_size=batch_size, bindings=bindings)
    # Transfer predictions back from the GPU.
    [cuda.memcpy_dtoh_async(out.host, out.device, stream) for out in outputs]
    # [cuda.memcpy_dtoh(out.host, out.device) for out in outputs]
    # Synchronize the stream
    stream.synchronize()
    # Return only the host outputs.

    return [out.host for out in outputs]
```

More info:

> TensorRT: 6.1.5 
>   Python: 2.7 
>   rosversion: 1.14.3 
>   rosdistro: melodic

Comment: Although loosely related,  I got the same message when I forgot to 
__import pycuda.autoinit__

Answer (score 9):

You need to explicitly create Cuda Device and load Cuda Context in the worker thread i.e. your callback function, instead of using `import pycuda.autoinit` in the main thread, as follows

```py
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import threading

def callback():
    cuda.init()
    device = cuda.Device(0)  # enter your Gpu id here
    ctx = device.make_context()

    allocate_buffers()  # load Cuda buffers or any other Cuda or TenosrRT operations

    ctx.pop()  # very important


if __name__ == "__main__":
    worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=callback())
    worker_thread.start()
    worker_thread.join()
```

Note: do not forget to remove `import pycuda.autoinit` in both modules

This is also discussed in a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601029/pycuda-with-flask-gives-pycuda-driver-logicerror-cumoduleloaddataex)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried to init ctx manually but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this error by doing:

1)delete from the code to stop autoloading cuda:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
```

2)check you're using correct label file/ number of classes and names of classes

3)you need to initialize manually cuda device; if you're using multithread/multiproccess in the code, add the following lines outside! of your engine/model/utils.py inference behavoir file (i.e. in the code where you call the inference behavior file):

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda

#before you call the inference/detection:
cuda.init() 
device = cuda.Device(0) 
self.ctx = device.make_context() 

#after you finished the operations of inference/detection:
self.ctx.pop()
```

Answer (score -2):

please init cuda.

1. As answers above.
2. `import pycuda.driver as cuda` in main.py or befor `import cuda-XXX-process`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30457522)