# Python multiprocessing with TensorRT

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pycuda, tensorrt

I am trying to use a TensorRT engine for inference in a python class that inherits from multiprocessing. The engine works in a standalone python script on my system, but now while integrating it into the codebase, the multiprocessing used in the class seems to be causing problems.

I am not getting any errors. It just skips everything after the line `self.runtime = trt.Runtime(self.trt_logger)`. My debugger from vscode does not go into the function either.

[In the docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/best-practices/index.html#thread-safety) the following is mentioned, that I do not fully understand:

> The TensorRT builder may only be used by one thread at a time. If you
> need to run multiple builds simultaneously, you will need to create
> multiple builders. The TensorRT runtime can be used by multiple
> threads simultaneously, so long as each object uses a different
> execution context.

The following parts of my code are started, joined and terminated from another file:

```py
# more imports
import logging
import multiprocessing
import tensorrt as trt
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit

class MyClass(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, messages):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        # other stuff
        self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()

    def load_tensorrt_model(self, config):
        '''Load tensorrt model with engine'''
        logging.debug('Start')

        # Reading the config parameters related to the engine
        engine_file = config['trt_engine']['trt_folder'] + os.path.sep + config['trt_engine']['engine_file']
        class_names_file = config['trt_engine']['trt_folder'] + os.path.sep + config['trt_engine']['class_names_file']

        # Verify if all the necessary files are present, if so load the detection network
        if os.path.exists(engine_file) and os.path.exists(class_names_file):
            try:
                logging.debug('In try statement')
                self.trt_logger = trt.Logger()
                f = open(engine_file, 'rb')
                logging.debug('I can get here, but no further')
                self.runtime = trt.Runtime(self.trt_logger)
                logging.debug('Cannot get here')
                self.engine = self.runtime.deserialize_cuda_engine(f.read())
# More stuff
```

I have found someone with a [multithreading problem](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-use-tensorrt-by-the-multi-threading-package-of-python/123085/8), but as of now I was unable to use this to solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

System specs:

- Python 3.6.9
- Jetson NX
- Jetpack 4.4.1
- L4T 32.4.4
- Tensorrt 7.1.3.0-1
- Cuda10.2
- Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: It's hard to say what's the problem since there's no "run" method in your multiprocessing class - so we can't see what's running in the multiprocess (aka in the background) and what is not.  Maybe this could help: https://medium.com/@sampsa.riikonen/doing-python-multiprocessing-the-right-way-a54c1880e300

Comment: Refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60752402/9116566

Answer (score 0):

same problem. It seems pycuda autoinit not working well under a multi process scenario.

try to replace `import pycuda.autoinit` with

```
cuda.init()
self.cuda_context = cuda.Device(0).make_context()
```